# How to add Custom JS and CSS file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme

I want to add a JS and CSS file for my theme. How would i do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`How to add Css file`**

Create this file like :-

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/theme/web/css/custom.css
```

And open your adding file like :-

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

Add this code :-

```
<css src="css/custom.css" order="100"/>
```

**`How to add JS file`**

Create this file like :-

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/theme/web/js/custom.js
```

And open your adding file like :-

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

Add this code :-

```
<script src="js/custom.js"/>
```

**`NOTE:-`**

Either the `<link src="js/custom.js"/>` or `<script src="js/custom.js"/>` instruction can be used to add a locally stored JavaScript file to your theme.

And last after you all changes run some commands like :-

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
And apply your permission
```

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: I have follow these steps but didn't shows js file @Mohit

Comment: Js file add in js folder??? If yes you remove var/cache folder and var/view_ processes folder and run all commands

Comment: It worked Thanks for that @Mohit
But it saves the file in pub/static so on view source the file it doesn't show any way to show or its a Magento  default Behaviour.
Will i have to always clear that folder and run those commands for a small change.

Comment: will you please help me with this about JS addition @Mohit .

Comment: Will you tell me how to get site url in my JS file @Mohit